# Pulling data from Object Array C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

[image: Array from Object]

Looking at the above example I'm wondering how I can convert the `requestedClass` which is of type `object` into an array for me to read from.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public object Get(string table, string columns, int id)
    {
        var splitColumns = columns.Split(',');
        var t = new propertyModel()
        {
            gallery = _db.PROPERTYGALLERies.Where(p => p.propertyId == id).ToList(),
            property = _db.PROPERTies.SingleOrDefault(p => p.id == id)
        };

        var requestedClass = t.GetType().GetProperty(table.ToLower()).GetValue(t, null);
        var returnArray = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
        var requestArray = new List<string>();

        foreach (var column in splitColumns)
        {
            foreach (var field in StringProperties(requestedClass, column))
            {
                requestArray.Add(field.Value);
            }
        }

        returnArray.Add(table, requestArray);

        return Json(returnArray, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> StringProperties(object obj, string column)
    {
        return from p in obj.GetType().GetProperties()
               where p.Name == column
               select new KeyValuePair<string, string>(p.Name, Convert.ToString(p.GetValue(obj)));
    }
```

Comment: Sorry for short question, trying to sort dinner for two little ones and also sort this issue out :D

Comment: Can you please show your code as a plain text, not as an image?

Comment: Yeah sure, two seconds

Comment: What is the value of `requestedClass.GetType()`?

Comment: @TheAngrySaxon - You can remove the image. We don't need both.

Comment: All added :) Sorry about that, was as image to show the result of the requestedClass

Comment: @DangerZone I think it's still pertinent, if you don't still I can remove for sure. Just it shows the result of `requestedClass`

Comment: @TheAngrySaxon - I'm just saying 98% of that screenshot is now duplicated so it's mostly irrelevant. Might make more sense to just post the result as text.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior the value is {Name = "propertyModel" FullName = "Data.propertyModel"}

Comment: I shall update in a min @DangerZone when I've got these two little ones off to bed

Comment: @TheAngrySaxon: What is a `Data.propertyModel`? The debug visualizer makes it look like some kind of collection of objects, but it's clearly not an Array. What other types does it extend or implement?

Comment: Data.propertyModel holds an `IEnumerable<propertyGallery>` and `PROPERTy` Class. PROPERTy is able to work correctly but I can't iterate through the `IEnumerable<>` due to not knowing how to convert the dynamic class. I've managed to serialise it into a JSON object which I might be able to hash into something but that's the only way so far I've actually managed to figure out how to work with the data that's stored into `requestedClass`

Answer (score 3):

You can just cast it to whatever the proper underlying type is. If the object is actually, for instance, an instance of `DataObject[]` you can just do:

```
DataObject[] mydataObjectArray = (DataObject[])requestedClass;
```

And you should be all set. Keep in mind, `DataObject` is just a made up class I am using to illustrate the concept. Whatever `requestedClass` was originally before it was cast as an `object` is what you will need to cast it to.

Comment: Problem I have is that I'm grabbing the object class dynamically. As far I can see atm there's no way of getting the data type into a variable to use in this way.

Comment: It depends on what you are wanting to do with it. You can use `requestedClass.GetType()` and use reflection for any number of things. Like I said though, it all depends on what you are wanting to do with it.

Comment: Let me create a video quick to show you my requirements... and issues

Comment: We don't need a video. Just describe what you are trying to achieve. Maybe include some pseudo-code as an example to provide some context.

Comment: Basically I'm trying to call a URL such as `/{controller}/{action}/{table}/{fields}/{id}` and the API to pass back the selected fields from selected table. It works perfectly for a `SingleOrDefault()` data type but when it's stored in an array I'm getting this issue of not being able to convert into something I can iterate through.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you know about the object at compile-time. If all you know is that it's an `IEnumerable<>`, you should be able to cast it like this:

```
object[] values = ((IEnumerable<object>)requestedClass).ToArray();
```

If you also know that it always contains `Data.PROPERTYGALLERY` objects, you could cast the items to end up with a more strongly-typed array:

```
Data.PROPERTYGALLERY[] values = ((IEnumerable<object>)requestedClass)
    .Cast<Data.PROPERTYGALLERY>()
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know what object Class they'll be requesting. Basically I'm trying to call a URL such as /{controller}/{action}/{table}/{fields}/{id} and the API to pass back the selected fields from selected table. It works perfectly for a SingleOrDefault() data type but when it's stored in an array I'm getting this issue of not being able to convert into something I can iterate through.

Comment: This was actually so so close to the end result that I'm upvoting but can't push it as the correct answer. If you want to alter the answer slightly to read `IEnumerable<object> collection = (IEnumerable<object>)requestedClass;` and then it was a case of foreach on the `collection`. I'll mark it as the Answer.

Comment: @TheAngrySaxon: Let me know if my updated answer is sufficiently correct.

Comment: No, there's no need to convert `toArray()` as it was already seen as one. All that I needed to do was store each object array into an `IEnumerable<object>` I'm not even sure if I need to cast to an `IEnumerable<object>` as well TBH. The model class needed to be left ambiguous as it was being set during runtime.

Comment: @TheAngrySaxon: "Looking at the above example I'm wondering how I can convert the requestedClass which is of type object into an array for me to read from." The `ToArray()` ensures that it's an array. If you don't need an array, just omit that call.